# Parse SDK methods not working in Xcode 6.3 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

So far I am having issues with blocks like this:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("success")
        } else {
            println("\(error)");
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        }
    }
```

When I add this into Xcode I get this:

```
Cannot invoke 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool!, NSError!) -> Void)'
```

When I run this code in Xcode 6.3 (non beta) it works fine. But in the Beta it fails and wont allow me to build. Any ideas if this will be cleared up or if there is a different implementation that I could use. Ive tried using just the signUpInBackgroundWithTarget but Im just not able to access the error correctly if one is received.

Answer (score 9):

be sure you are using SDK version 1.7.1, then removing the types from your closure should do the trick:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("success")
    } else {
        println("\(error)");
        // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the new addition of "Nullability Annotations" to Swift 1.2, you have to rewrite the code above like this (using Parse 1.7.1+):

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        println(error) // there is an error, print it
    } else {
        if succeeded {
            println("success")
        } else {
            println("failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Parse is now returning optionals (?) instead of explicitely unwrapped objects (!).

Comment: Strange, but Xcode show me error: `Cannot invoke 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool, NSError?) -> Void)'`

Comment: @orkenstein are you on at least Parse 1.7.1?

Answer (score 1):

Notation of Swift is changed

```
class AAPLList : NSObject, NSCoding, NSCopying { 
    // ...
    func itemWithName(name: String!) -> AAPLListItem!
    func indexOfItem(item: AAPLListItem!) -> Int

    @NSCopying var name: String! { get set }
    @NSCopying var allItems: [AnyObject]! { get }
    // ...
}
```

After annotations:

```
class AAPLList : NSObject, NSCoding, NSCopying { 
    // ...
    func itemWithName(name: String) -> AAPLListItem?
    func indexOfItem(item: AAPLListItem) -> Int

    @NSCopying var name: String? { get set }
    @NSCopying var allItems: [AnyObject] { get }
    // ...
}
```

So you can change

`(succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in`

to

`(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in`

Answer (score 0):

Which Parse SDK are you using? They released version 1.7.1 a few days ago that should fix your issue.

Comment: Is there anything special I need to do to upgrade to 1.7.1? I removed 1.7.0 and dragged in 1.7.1 and I still get the same error

Comment: Nope....it says in the release notes that it should of fixed your problem so it might be something on the Xcode side of things

Comment: Ok, I may try start a new project with it from scratch and see if I get it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
(succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

to

```
(succeeded, error) -> Void in
```

This change is required due to changes in the Parse SDK